# How to avoid that '@RepeatedTest Annotation runs BeforeEach and AfterEach in JUnit'?

Tags: java, testing, junit, annotations, automated-tests

I have the following problem with JUnit 5.
I want to run a test 15 times, so i used the Annotation `@RepeatedTest(15)` and it worked. But the problem is, that in every run it calls `@BeforeEach` Method and `@AfterEach` Method.
Its doing this for all 15 loops, but it should only call `@BeforeEach`before the first run and `@AfterEach` after the last run. I think i cant use `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` because i have multiple Tests, so this would only be called before Test 1 and Test 50 for example.

### How it runs at the moment:

```
@BeforeAll Method
Test 1:
    - @BeforeEach Method
    - Run1
    - @AfterEach Method
    - @BeforeEach Method
    - Run2
    - @AfterEach Method
Test 2:
    - @BeforeEach Method
    - Run1
    - @AfterEach Method
    - @BeforeEach Method
    - Run2
    - @AfterEach Method
@AfterAll Method
```

### How it should run:

```
@BeforeAll Method
Test 1:
    - @BeforeEach Method
    - Run1
    - Run2
    - @AfterEach Method
Test 2:
    - @BeforeEach Method
    - Run1
    - Run2
    - @AfterEach Method
@AfterAll Method
```

Comment: Apparently your idea of @RepeatedTest does not correspond to the implementation of the test framework. Maybe you could elaborate a bit more about the specific use case. Then it might be easier to make alternative suggestions.

Comment: The tests are used for performance testing. 
The `@BeforeEach` Method creates a .jtl File.
While the tests are running there is done some Measurement. The Measurement data is written to an Array, holding the information about start, stop, elapsed Time, etc. When the test is done, `@AfterEach` is called. In this Method, I loop through the array and write the data to the .jtl file and close it finally. The problem is that with `@RepeatedTests(15)` its creating 15 Files because it's calling 15 times `@BeforeEach`. Instead, it should create 1 File with the data of the 15 Runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see four options here:

1. Create a new test class per scenario each with one `@RepeatedTest` method and use `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` for measurements.
2. Don't use `@RepeatedTest`, but do your repetitions and measurements inside a normal `@Test`.
3. Let JUnit inject `RepetitionInfo` where needed to decide about executions:

   ```java
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepetitionInfo;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo;

   class RepeatTest {

       @BeforeEach
       void setUp(RepetitionInfo repetitionInfo, TestInfo testInfo) {
           if (repetitionInfo.getCurrentRepetition() == 1) {
               System.out.println("Before repetition of " + testInfo.getDisplayName());
           }
       }

       @RepeatedTest(value = 3, name = "{displayName}_{currentRepetition}of{totalRepetitions}") @DisplayName("test1")
       void test1(TestInfo testInfo) {
           System.out.println(testInfo.getDisplayName());
       }

       @RepeatedTest(value = 5, name = "{displayName}_{currentRepetition}of{totalRepetitions}") @DisplayName("test2")
       void test2(TestInfo testInfo) {
           System.out.println(testInfo.getDisplayName());
       }

       @AfterEach
       void tearDown(RepetitionInfo repetitionInfo, TestInfo testInfo) {
           if (repetitionInfo.getCurrentRepetition() == repetitionInfo.getTotalRepetitions()) {
               System.out.println("After repetition of " + testInfo.getDisplayName());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Before repetition of test1_1of3
   test1_1of3
   test1_2of3
   test1_3of3
   After repetition of test1_3of3
   Before repetition of test2_1of5
   test2_1of5
   test2_2of5
   test2_3of5
   test2_4of5
   test2_5of5
   After repetition of test2_5of5
   ```
4. Consider implementing a small JUnit Extension, if you have lots of tests like that. Maybe introducing some new method annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution!
I dont know why, but for every Test Class `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` is called.
So I deleted the `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` Methods and move their code to `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll`.

### Now they run like this:

```
@BeforeAll Method
Test 1:
    - Run1
    - Run2
@AfterAll Method
@BeforeAll Method
Test 2:
    - Run1
    - Run2
@AfterAll Method
```

And I get the expected output of one .jtl File with the data of 15 Runs on each Test Case.

Comment: Yes, `@BeforeAll`/`@AfterAll` run once per test class.